# CentOS - SSH Tunneling: How to use another server's network

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

Assume two CentOS instances are connected to the internet‌ (Say server A: 5.200.200.5 and B: 46.30.7.20).

I want to create a setup on servers in which all network traffic of server A passes through server B. So that when server A sends a request to a third server, for example, Google, the IP of server B is transmitted. I have SSH access to both servers.

For this purpose, I prefer not to use OpenVPN. I read many articles on Google and StackExchange about `SSH Tunneling` or `Port Forwarding` in Linux. But none of them explain a step by step solution or are written for highly expert users.

Comment: Of these articles you read, please provide some links, what exactly you attempted, and why it did not solve your problem.  And what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case you might have some luck with ssh's `-D`option (dynamic tunnelling)?

If so, this:

`serverA:~$ ssh -D 1234 serverB`

would allow *serverA* to use its *localhost:1234*-port as a dynamic (SOCKS) proxy, and this traffic would swoop through the tunnel and appear outside *serverB* as if it originated on *serverB*.

If you're looking for something more VPN-like you'll probably need some kind of real VPN - maybe the lighter-weight *wireguard* or *tinc* perhaps?